# Full Text Search not working with numbers

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have this table with song titles, artist etc.

`| id | artist      | title | search_tags    |`

`| 1  | miley cyrus |   23  | miley cyrus 23 |`

This is my query:

`select * from music where match(search_tags) against ('+$search_value*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

It works fine when I search: `miley` but it doesn't show any results when `search_tags = 23`

Note: I'm using MySQL 5.6 with InnoDB on Windows 10 and `ft_min_word_len=1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When searching for "23" will not work because the length of the key is small. 
MySQL by default stored keys in the fulltext index with a min of 4 characters. you will need to change that to 1 or 2 for your query to work.

What you need to do here is

1. Add this line to your my.ini file

   innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1
2. Restart MySQL Service
3. After the server comes back up, rebuild your tables by issuing a fake ALTER command.

   ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=INNODB;

Run the query again and it should work :)

Good Luck

Comment: ft_min_word_len is 1; It is on the question too. @Mike

Comment: oh, sorry I missed that. Try to rebuild your indexed. I am not sure id you changed ft_min_word_len after creating the index or not.

Comment: ft_min_word_len was changed after creating the index and innodb_ft_min_token_size returns 3 @Mike

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot man, especially for this `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=INNODB;`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that ft_min_word_len is 4 by default. The token 500 is length 3. thus it will not be indexed at all. You will have to do three(3) things:

STEP 01 : Open the init file inside mysql folder
Add this to \bin\mysql\mysql5.7.24

innodb_ft_min_token_size = 1

STEP 02 : Restart mysql

STEP 03 : Reindex all indexes in the models table
You could just drop and add the FULLTEXT index